# IndexOutOfBoundsError MergeSort Python

Tags: python, recursion, merge, mergesort

i am sorry for asking and very new to this,
But thus i am not allowed by my Prof to touch the merge_sort
and i can't do it any better than what the current merge is,
plis help me.

The Question is, how do i get the merge_`enter code here`sort running, without touching merge_sort and only rewriting merge(s, s1, s2) ?

```
def merge(s1, s2, s):
    i = j = 0
    while i + j < len(s1 + s2):
        if i == len(s2) or ((i < len(s1)) and s1[i] < s2[j]):
            s[i + j] = s1[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            s[i + j] = s2[j]
            j += 1


def merge_sort(s):
    n = len(s)
    if n < 2:
        return
    mid = n // 2
    s1 = s[0:mid]
    s2 = s[mid:n]
    merge_sort(s1), merge_sort(s2)
    merge(s1, s2, s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    S = [1, 7, 3, 5, 4, 2]
    merge_sort(S)
    print(S)
```

Comment: which function you cant modify? and are you trying to achieve merge sort functionality?

Comment: we are not allowed to touch merge_sort(s). We shall implement merge(S, S1, S2)

Comment: Unless you're writing merge as an assignment, don't do it - the built-in `sort` method is faster!  I came across this just a couple of days ago: https://earthly.dev/blog/python-timsort-merge/

Comment: It's acually not an assignment, more alike selfstudy. All the other sorting algorithms like quicksort i understood quite well, but merge sort kinda kept me stuck for a while. The article is fascinating, thank you for that kind sir, but thus our prof insists on the worst case input n > 2^1024, it's probably useless to show him that article.

Comment: At the very least you should use the built-in sort for the largest segments you can before switching to merging.

Answer (score 0):

```
def merge(s1, s2, s):
    i = j = k = 0
    while i < len(s1) and j < len(s2):
        if s1[i] < s2[j]:
            s[k] = s1[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            s[k] = s2[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1
    
    while i < len(s1):
        s[k] = s1[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1
    while j < len(s2):
        s[k] = s2[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def merge(S1, S2, S):
for s in range(0, len(S)):
    if len(S2) == 0:
        S[s] = S1[0]
        S1.pop(0)
    elif len(S1) == 0:
        S[s] = S2[0]
        S2.pop(0)
    elif S1[0] < S2[0]:
        S[s] = S1[0]
        S1.pop(0)
    else:
        S[s] = S2[0]
        S2.pop(0)
```

solved nvm, ty for your answers